# Mux operation with feedback loops

Tags: multiplexer

I'm helping a young friend with a homework problem... I took digital circuits 25 years ago and thought I could help her quick but I'm stumped!

This mux looks impossible but maybe that's because it's been so long I looked at this stuff

The bottom mux 10 input is tied to GND so that S1S0 is obvious. But the way the output is tied to inputs, sometimes through an inverter, sometimes not..
I'm just not seeing how this is possible?  It looks like the whole thing is indeterminate.

Don't solve it for us but I need a hint!!!!

Imma feel foolish I'm sure when one of you points out what I'm missing...

Edit...we realized 10 makes output 000.... still working on others

Edit:  we can write 10 and 01 in terms of Y0, Y1 and Y2 but all the 00 outputs still look impossible...maybe the professor expects an "X" for those???

[image: example mux]

Comment: Yes, indeed, lots of combo loops. Output becomes indeterminate.

Comment: for the record, if anyone in your career ever designs a circuit like this without a very, very good reason, fire them immediately. Even the seemingly intended behaviour (11 holds the last output without any change) might not actually work with real muxers. However, don't fire the guy who designs this but with an extra register on the output of each muxer, because that actually works.